# Check whether any field is filled in a specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 10 div tags in my form, in each div there are 5 select boxes. For example we take first div which contains 5 select boxes, here I want to check whether any 1 of the 5 select boxes is selected or not.

If any one selected I need to display some links in my page, if nothing is selected I need to hide the links.

Thanks.

Comment: can u post your HTML too so that it becomes easy for us to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using:

```
// Detect if a <select> has a value other than 0
function isSelected(){
    $('select').each(function(){
        if($(this).val() != '0'){
            return true;
        }
    });

    return false;
}

// Usage
if(isSelected()){
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: select box means dropdowns in which the initial value in each dropdown s '0' and selecting means changing the value from '0' to '1' or '2'...  in that dropdown

Comment: Ok, in future you should add such code to your questions, but I've updated my answer to reflect the question

Comment: +1 although in future @TomWalters, you might want to clarify with a comment on the question before answering with an assumption ;-)